# Store data in char buffer by incrementing the pointer till the end of allocated memory

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to store data to the char buffer pointed by the pointer credit_data.
I am incrementing the pointer every time i copy the data. After final increment, i am decrementing the pointer by having a counter on the number of bytes read and then use that to decrement the pointer and get the correct address. But when i try to print the final string stored in the buffer, i am getting NULL. I am new to pointers and pointer arithmetic. Please guide me.

```
#define DP_RMD_PERSON_TITLE_MAX_LEN     (64)
#define DP_RMD_FAMILY_TITLE_MAX_LEN     (64)
int CaluclateSizeOfCreditList()
{
    short dataset_idx = 0,str_len =0, num_datasets = 8; //variable
    str_len = sizeof(short);
    for (dataset_idx = 0; dataset_idx < num_datasets; dataset_idx++) {
        str_len += sizeof(short)  + DP_RMD_PERSON_TITLE_MAX_LEN + DP_RMD_PERSON_TITLE_MAX_LEN; 
    }
    return str_len;
}
void main () 
{
    unsigned char* credit_data = NULL;
    //unsigned char* dp_credit_data;
    short num_credits = 8 , classification = 2, dataset_idx = 0, i = 0, len = 0;
    char *person_title = "robert"; char *person_given_name = "Wuhl";

    len = CaluclateSizeOfCreditList();
    credit_data = (unsigned char *)malloc(len);
    if(!credit_data) return;
    memset(credit_data, 0x00, len);
    //dp_credit_data = credit_data;
    printf("\n credit_data pointing to address location %p",credit_data);

    *credit_data = num_credits;
    credit_data += sizeof(short);
    i += sizeof(short);
    for (dataset_idx = 0; dataset_idx < num_credits; dataset_idx++)
    {
        *credit_data = (unsigned char)classification;
        credit_data += sizeof(short);
        i += sizeof(short);

        len = strlen(person_title);
        len++;
        memcpy(credit_data,person_title,len);
        credit_data += DP_RMD_PERSON_TITLE_MAX_LEN;
        i += DP_RMD_PERSON_TITLE_MAX_LEN;

        len = strlen(person_given_name);
        len++;
        memcpy(credit_data,person_given_name,len);
        if(dataset_idx < 7)
        {
            credit_data += DP_RMD_PERSON_TITLE_MAX_LEN;
            i += DP_RMD_PERSON_TITLE_MAX_LEN;
        }
    }
    *credit_data = '\0';
    printf("\n credit_data pointing to address location after increment %p",credit_data);
    credit_data = credit_data - i;
    //credit_data = dp_credit_data;
    printf("\ncredit_data is [%s]\n",credit_data);
//Free the allocated memory
}
```

Problem statement is, i have a structure whose member variable is an array of another structure.

```
  typedef struct _DP_RMD_CREDIT_
  {
     DP_RMD_CREDIT_TYPE      classification; //ENUM     
     UBYTE                   *person_title;        
     UBYTE                   *person_given_name;   
     UBYTE                   *person_family_name;  
     UBYTE                   *organisation;        
  } DP_RMD_CREDIT;

  typedef struct _DP_RMD_CREDIT_LIST_
  {
     USHORT          num_credits;
     DP_RMD_CREDIT   credit[DP_RMD_MAX_CREDITS];
  } DP_RMD_CREDIT_LIST;
```

I want to store all the values of those member variables in a buffer and update to sqlite db as BLOB. Please assist me.

Comment: The code does not even compile at this line: `*credit_data = (unsigned char *)classification;`

Comment: May I have the pleasure of guiding you towards your debugger?

Comment: If you put binary data in a char buffer, don't think it will print as a string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code makes completely no sense (sorry to be so blunt).

Function `CaluclateSizeOfCreditList()` will always return 1042, so why have that function.

```
 *credit_data = num_credits;
 credit_data += sizeof(short);
```

The above places an int in `*credit_data`, then increments with size of `short`. Makes no sense.

```
    *credit_data = (unsigned char *)classification;
    credit_data += sizeof(int);
```

The above makes `classification` a pointer to `char` then copies that thing to `credit_data`. Here you think the compiler will convert the value of `classification` into a string of digits. Nono. Then you increment `credit_data` with the size of an `int`. You have two thoughts: `classification` is made into a string of digits (how many??); the original was an int so, increment with that size. Bad thinking.

```
*credit_data = '\0';
if(NULL != credit_data)
```

This terminates `credit_data` with a null character, as if it was a string (but it is filled with binary data), then you test if `credit_data` actually has memory (allocated from `malloc)`. Quite the other way around, I'd say.

And now you wonder why `printf` doesn't show anything...

I suggest you read a book on C.